# How does compiler infers type for generic exception type declared in throws

Tags: java, generics, exception

While looking for an elegant way for re-throwing exceptions I have stumbled across a mega-hackable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4375634/2856227) of Peter Lawrey.
The code is as follows:

```
/**
* Cast a CheckedException as an unchecked one.
*
* @param throwable to cast
* @param <T>       the type of the Throwable
* @return this method will never return a Throwable instance, it will just throw it.
* @throws T the throwable as an unchecked throwable
*/
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Throwable> RuntimeException rethrow(Throwable throwable) throws T {
    throw (T) throwable; // rely on vacuous cast
}
```

And usage:

```
} catch(AnyCheckedException e) {
    throw rethrow(e);
}
```

And my questions are:

1. How does compiler knows which type is `T`? 
   I have explicitly provided type params for method and IDE suggested is should be a `RuntimeException`. However how does compiler knows it?
2. Why does the real exception is being unimpededly casted to T (if compiler inferes T as `RuntimeException`)?

Comment: For number 2, the answer is already in the comment: `rely on vacuous cast`, i.e. it's not an actual cast at that point

Comment: Note the `@SuppressWarnings` there. That's for the unchecked cast.